# regex that match iff there are nor more than 4 alphabet at the end of the string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a regex that matches if the 5th last character is a non alpha character. So far I have not been successful. Though I have made one which is as follows:

```
.*[a-zA-Z]{5,}$
```

This checks if there are five or more alphabets at the end of string. But I want to have the opposite of that. the regex shall match only if there are less than five alphabets at the end of the string.

Comment: is your string length always `>5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

As suggested by a commenter, you could otherwise use the regex `[a-zA-Z]{,4}$`.  In this case, `{,4}` matches no more than 4 of the previous expression.  So it matches no more than 4 alphabet characters.

---

To match any string does not not contain 4 consecutive alphabet characters at the end of the string, you can simply use this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> r=re.compile('(?![a-zA-Z]{4}$).{4}$')
>>> r.search('hello.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb759cdb0>
>>> r.search('hellobcom')
>>> 
>>> r.search('hello.ca')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb759cdb0>
```

Explanation of the regex `(?![a-zA-Z]{4}$).{4}$`:
`(?!` means to begin a negative lookahead (matches only if the contents of `()` do *not*  match).
`[a-zA-Z]{4}` matches any 4 characters in the alphabet.
`$` is the end of the line.
`)` is the end of the negative lookahead group.
`.{4}` matches any 4 characters.
`$` is the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
[^a-zA-Z].{4}$
```

Explanation:

```
[^a-zA-Z] = match anything except alphabets
.{4} = any 4 characters
$ = end of string
```

Comment: OP needs the 5th character from the end to be a non-char

Comment: Exactly. The fifth character from the end shall be a non alphabet rest can be any character.

Comment: Just a quick remark, this doesn't check that the last 4 characters are  alphabets. If you want to check that the last 5 are 1 non-alphabet followed by 4 alphabets, you need to use `[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]{4}$` instead

Comment: @ Dogbert @nbarraille I have tried it but didnt worked. Here is the output. >>> print re.match("[^a-zA-Z].{4}$","sad.xyz@gmail.com") None I guess I have not been able to explain it in the right way since my english sucks. The regex shall only match if there less than 4 alphabets at the end of string. abc@xyz.com shall match but not abx@xyz.abcde since there should not be more than 4 alphabets at the end of the string.

Comment: @yasra002 Change `{4}` to `{,4}` to check for "no more than 4 alphabetic characters".